# Find a specific type of file stored deep in the system

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7

May i know if there are any cmd or run commands to find a specific type of file stored deeper than a number of folders.
eg:I want to find a .docx file which is stored deeper than 2 files in C drive
   C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\sample1.docx
   C:\Folder1\Folder2\sample2.docx
I want the result to show me only sample1 and not sample2
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /s c:\sample1.docx
```

should locate your file.

```
dir /s /b c:\sample1.docx
```

should respond just with the full filepath

Comment: I'm afraid, this time you understood the question wrong.

Comment: @Stephan : Yet, it would appear so.